# Why might a non-empty Kotlin ArrayList throw an out-of-bounds error at index 0?

Tags: kotlin, arraylist

The following Kotlin Android code sometimes throws an IndexOutOfBounds exception:

```
if (mPointQueue.isNotEmpty()) {
   mPointRecycle.add(mPointQueue.removeAt(0))
}
```

mPointQueue is an ArrayList. It's not shared across multiple threads. How can an non-empty ArrayList have nothing at index 0? Doesn't it have something at index 0 by definition?

The error does seem to occur when the user is scrolling through screens very quickly. Could it be a race condition, if that code is executed twice in rapid succession, or something odd like that? (ie the underpinning array is still copying in the background when `isNotEmpty()` is called, giving an erroneous result??)

And what can I do to prevent the error, other than catching and, I dunno, ignoring it?

thanks

Comment: It seems highly likely that this is "shared across multiple threads". If that is the case, a simple solution is to just lock that section of the code with `synchronized(mPointQueue) { ... }`

Comment: In which lifecycle method, you call this line? Maybe the framework calls the method twice, and there is an interruption after the if, so the second call throws an exception. Or, to make sure, add some logging to your methods. Then you could confirm potential race/multiple call (and print the array content as well).

Comment: I know that the coment I'm about to make might be silly, but have you try debuggin it? Also, you can make change your code and create methods for acessing the mPointQueue variable. If something is trying to alter it's state, the debug should be able catch it if you put a breakpoint on those methods.